# Switch Layout in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-gridview

I want to switch layout. when press ImageButton map, it goes to map view and when I press ImageButton gridview, it's goes to GridView.

Note: map is in another layout. grid is in another layout and picture in gridview is call from another layout

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Have a fragment created for each of the Views. Then, depending on what you are using for a parent Layout View, you can add the appropriate Fragment to the parent layout when the particular view is first displayed.

When you're switching between views, put the current view (the one that is going to be hidden) on to the fragment backstack (you'll have to take a look at [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) as well). Then when you go to switch again, you can pop the already existing fragment off the stack and place the current Fragment on to the stack.

EDIT: Depending on what API you are developing (Fragments were introduced in API 13) you may need to add the compatibility library to your project

Answer (score 0):

Either call `setContentView(int layoutId)` from your click handler or start a new Activity with the map layout in that Activity.

Comment: when setContentView(R.layout.my_layout), it's cover all the layout that mean it's cover the ImageButton above too, so i can't see ImageButton above

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is to have 2 activities, unless you have reasons not to have more than one.
GridViewActivity
MapViewActivity
When you click on a image on the GridViewActivity you start the MapViewActivity activity and vice versa. 
Just make sure you have the imagebutton in the two layouts(of course ids should be different).

Answer (score 0):

Create a holder view (eg. RelativeLayout) in your main xml. Then, create 2 seperate XML files for the gridview and mapview.

When the appropriate button is pressed, you can inflate and attach the correct view to your holder view. For efficiency, you can even use the ViewHolder paradigm to cache the already inflated views.

Hope this helps...

**EDIT based on question below**

Sample code (typed on the fly as don't have access to my working version at the current location).

main.xml contains

```
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/x".../>
```

You also have image.xml and map.xml.  In your OnClick, try:

```
    ViewGroup myLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.x);
    View myView;
    if (clickedButton == imageButton) {
        myView = getInflater().inflate(R.layout.image, myLayout, false);
    } else if (clickedButton == mapButton) {
        myView = getInflater().inflate(R.layout.map, myLayout, false);
    }
    myLayout.addView(myView);
```

Comment: I used to use layout for inflate that get another layout and place it in my main layout but nothing shown. can u give me some example or tutorial or simple project. thanks in advance